# Copy button for code blocks

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes when I want to help people I copy their code to compile it. If the code is long, this can take some effort. How about a copy button for each code block?

Comment: This would be useful. As a workaround I edit the post (if possible) and copy the code from that window as it's easier than the preview IMO. Then I just cancel my edit.

Comment: I wonder if  a question with that much code (which needs such a button) really has a MCVE.

Comment: @Tom Sure, it can be an indication, but nowhere near a proof.